# Can't compile SDL with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction, frameworks, sdl

I will be doing my graduating project on both SDL and SFML libraries. I tried installing the first one with the help of [this](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/mac/xcode/) tutorial. I did everything I was supposed to (except installing templates. I don't need that) and when I entered the code, it said compiling failed. This is what it showed me. [image]

I clicked on the red exclamation mark hoping I would find out more. This is what I got. [image]

Do you know what I should do to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Is the SDL library 64-bit? Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I don't know, but I've read that it doesn't matter since the 32 bit would still work but slower.